# Error about insertion adapter. [Error]conversion from 'back_insert_iterator<vector<>>' to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c++

I am learning cpp, and now have a problem.

I don't know what should I do to deal with this.

[Error] conversion from 'std::back_insert_iterator >' to non-scalar type 'std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}' requested.

## Here is the code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>    
using namespace std;

template <typename readPointer, typename writePointer, typename type, typename compare> 
writePointer filter(readPointer begin, readPointer end, writePointer at, type val, compare comp){
    while((begin=find_if(begin,end,bind2nd(comp,val)))!=end){
        *at = *begin;
        begin++;
        at++;
    }
    return at;
}

int main(){
    float a[19] = {1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5,9.5,8.5,7.5,6.5,5.5,4.5,3.5,2.5,1.5};
    float a1[19] = {0};
    vector<float> v(a,a+19);
    vector<float> v1;
    vector<float>::iterator itr_end = filter(v.begin(),v.end(),back_inserter(v1),6,less<float>());
    vector<float>::iterator itr = v1.begin();
    for(itr;itr!=itr_end;itr++){
        cout << *itr << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `filter` doesn't return a `vector<float>::iterator`. Make it `filter(...);  vector<float>::iterator itr_end = v1.end();`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you very much ! Your answer is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am careless, the variable type of itr_end which is used to receive the return value of the function filter() does not match the real type.

So I should write like this.

```
back_insert_iterator<vector<float>> itr_end = filter(v.begin(),v.end(),back_inserter(v1),6,less<float>());
```

Igor Tandetnik solved my problem in the comment area.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use remove_copy_if?

```
remove_copy_if(v.begin(),v.end(),back_inserter(v1),[](float v) { return v < 6;});
```